# can't convert Hash into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

CSV file
I have 1000 files in one directory. I want to call all the CSV files in that directory and execute `if` condition. If condition satisfies it should print `name` else it should print `"nothing"`

Example of csv:

```
name,id,address,country,food
A,11,bcvhcbdc,india,biryani
```

...

```
require "csv"

path="/logs/*exception_evaluation_summary.csv"

#calling csv files in the directory
Dir.glob(path).each do |f|
  #reading csv files
  csv = CSV.read(f, :headers=>true, :encoding => "bom|utf-8")

  csv.each do |record|
    if (record['id'] != 0 && record['country']=="india" && record['food']=="biryani") 
      print record[name]
    else
      print "nothing"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am new to ruby. can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in `print record[name]`, change it to `print record['name']` and you should be fine:

```
csv.each do |record|
  if (record['id'] != 0 && record['country']=="india" && record['food']=="biryani") 
    print record['name']
  else
    print "nothing"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Gerry but still hitting the error                         /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:98:in `read': can't convert Hash into Integer (TypeError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:98:in `read'
 from calling.rb:7
 from calling.rb:6:in `each'
 from calling.rb:6

Comment: @user1656716 The error simply says that in that line (98) you are using a `Hash` when an `Integer` is expected. Can you share your `csv.rb` code around line `98` and your `calling.rb` code?